# Removing specific node(s) from STL List

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list

I need a list of items (some object) to be maintained with the following operations supported:

- Insertion at end
- Removal from any pos

STL list seems to be the right choice. However, how can I do the 2nd operation in constant time? I could save pointer to each Node somewhere and delete them directly, but erase takes an iterator so that wouldn't work.

Example usage:

```
items = list<myobj>..
items.push_back(obj1)
items.push_back(obj2)
items.push_back(obj3)
items.remove(obj2) // <- How to do this in constant time.
```

If push_back somehow gave access to node, i could've used:

```
map[obj1] = items.push_back(obj1)
items.remove(map[obj1])
```

One option is to use iterator in the map, Is there any simpler way?

Comment: Instead of saving a pointer, cant you just save an iterator instead?  Also, what do you mean by constant time? Simply removing an object from a std::list at any position is constant, but finding an object is not.

Comment: The problem is if there are n items in list, I have to save n iterators. That doesn't look like an elegant solution (btw, I'm a C++ newbie)

Comment: Depending your use case, you might want to just use an std::vector. It's relatively inefficient to remove items, O(n), but constant time to access them, and it could be constant time to remove them too if you're okay with just setting an item to null (if you're storing pointers) or a special value in your object. Would take more memory of course, but is that an issue?

Comment: Do you need a list of items or simply a collection?  What is the purpose of this collection?  What operations will you be performing on it?  Search?  Iterate?  How will you consume them?

Comment: Operations are the only ones mentioned above. I'll edit the question and add an example.

Comment: You haven't explained how you'll be consuming the list, but if you're going to be the one consuming it (i.e. you're not passing the iterator to an outside function), my modified answer will take care of your needs in constant time perfectly. Otherwise, you can write your own iterator to bridge between my solution below and your consumer function.

Answer (score 2):

A compromise would be a red-black tree like most std::set implementations. It's O(log n) for insert, search, and delete. Trees are basically the ultimate compromise data structure. They're not amazing for anything, but they always get the job done well enough.

Otherwise, profile your code with both a linked list and a vector, and find out if resizing the vector is really as terrible as it could be (this'll depend on how often you do it).

---

There may be a better (inelegant, but very effective) solution that might just take care of your problems. You haven't mentioned how you'll be consuming the list, but if you can set aside a value as being unused, you can use a vector and simply mark an element as deleted instead of actually deleting it. Or use a vector and a have a separate bitset (or C++03 `vector<bool>`) telling you if an item is deleted or valid. To delete it, you just have to flip the bit in the bitmap. When iterating, just remember to check the deletion bitmap before processing the content. If memory isn't an issue and only speed matters and easiness/clarity matter, replace the `vector<object>` with `vector<pair<bool, object>>` where the `bool` is the deletion flag.

Comment: +1 for RB-trees, we can also store pointers to non-unique objects there.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). This allows you to combine several indices over a data structure. So you can have constant time lookup and removal of any element, at the expense of linear space overhead.